# making one cell equal either of 2 cells if filled

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to create a multi page sheet with cells that are 01:30 AM/PM time formatted.  I'm trying to make cell c6 on sheet 3 equal cell c7 on sheet 2 or cell d8 on sheet 2 if one is filled and nothing if neither is filled.  Both would not be filled at the same time as they are arrival times.  I've gotten as far as IF (Sheet2!D7 <>,Sheet2!D7,Sheet2!C7)  however if both are blank it automatically reports 12:00 am.

Comment: please post some sample data with desired output, currently it's difficult to understand your question.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 1):

Nest your IFs:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet2!D7="",Sheet2!C7=""),"",IF(Sheet2!D7<>"",Sheet2!D7,Sheet2!C7))
```